# BI - How to design a data model to compare orders price vs cost in a star schema

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-modeling, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm struggling triying to make a star schema from a set of tables with different origins, two SQL databases, Excel files and CSV reports, it's a bit of a puzzle.

The initial tables that they provide me are set like this:

[image: Initial tables]

The important points of this set of tables are:

- In Products table IdProduct is not unique, because one product can be make with one type of machine in factory A, and another type of machine in factory B, so it's one row for every Factory/Machine/IdProduct combination.
- The OrderItems table has mixed rows with materials and products, so you have all the products in the Order and all the materials used in each product of the same Order.
- The cost of the material changes daily and is updated in the system from where I get the OrderItems table.
- The delivery cost is different for each order.
- The packaging and fix costs are updated once a week.
- The product price changes from order to order (it is set taking into account the client, day and size of the order).

I got to this model dividing the OrderItems in products and costs (materials), and joining with them the fixed costs and the packaging costs, I haven't joined the delivery costs, but i end up with two fact tables and a snowflake schema:

[image: Current model]

I am thinking in Region, Factory, Machine, Date, Product, and a compound of cost concepts (materials, fixed costs, etc.) as dimensions, and the total amounts and quantities as facts. This to compare the total sales to the total costs around the different dimensions.

I just wanna know if this is the correct path or there is a better way, I tried to search more about the subject but the case is too specific so I get nothing.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a star schema over a snowflake schema ?
The Star schema is in a more de-normalized form and can be better for performance. Along the same records the Star schema uses less foreign keys so the query execution time is limited. In almost all cases the data retrieval speed of a Star schema has the Snowflake beat.

But you can split your work as data marts :

> A data mart is a simple form of data warehouse focused on a single
> subject or line of business.

A data mart can contain star schemas and other tables for more than one warehouse pack. For example, a single data mart might contain data for the your reporting needs related to costs